How to set default dark text color in React Native without modifying AppTheme or creating a Text wrapper
In my React Native project, for Android, I'd like to set a default dark/light text colors for all Text components. Here are the constraints:

I don't want to modify the android/app/src/main/res/style.xml to change the AppTheme parent to Light or Dark from DayNight.
I want to avoid to create a custom wrapper component for Text.
I'd prefer not to define the color style for every single Text component in my project.

Is there a way to achieve this default light/dark text color behavior in React Native while adhering to these limitations?
I tried manually finding all Text components to set a default color, but that's risky because it would require changing a lot of code at once. Ideally, I'd like a solution that allows me to define a default dark color based on the theme. I was hoping to use the useColorScheme hook and somehow determine the color values from the root of the project to affect the entire application dynamically. While I currently want a light theme, I also need flexibility to switch to DayNight mode and adjust colors accordingly.

I would personally advise you to create a theme context, where you can centrally manage colors. In the theme context you can also define global styles, like brand colors, margins, padding etc.
For example, a simple theme could be something like that:
const ThemeContext = createContext();

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
const scheme = useColorScheme();
const theme = {
textColor: scheme === 'dark' ? '#FFFFFF' : '#000000' 
//you can add more theme properties here
}
 return (
<ThemeContext.Provider value={theme}>
  {children}
</ThemeContext.Provider> )
}

You can then define your own Text component that makes use of the textColor. Make sure to wrap your application's root component with ThemeProvider,  ensure that the theme context is available throughout your entire app.
const Text = ({ style, ...props }) => {
    const theme = useContext(ThemeContext);
    return <RNText style={[{ color: theme.textColor }, style]} {...props} />;
}

Now you can use the newly created Text component across the app for dynamic styling.

Your suggestions can be useful for someone with a similar issue, but as I mentioned in my question, making wrappers is not acceptable in my current situation. I tried to figure it out with AI, but got the same answer you mentioned exactly with "RNText" etc. Maybe you forgot to copy the import with alias for original Text from react-native. That's why I took the time to ask here. Anyway thanks for your effort.
